# New to VBA and am trying to create a conditional (If Or Then) code

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement, copy, paste

In an Excel doc, I'm trying to copy entire row values, AND preserve formatting AND formulas based on a couple of conditions in one particular column. I am new to this and can likely eventually figure out what I am doing, but have limited time to dedicate to it.

Below is what I've tried and is working to copy the values in column L that meet the conditions (bold text OR yellow highlights), but it does not preserve the formatting, nor does it copy the entire row of values and formulas.

```
Sub Button1_Click()

Dim myrange As Range
Dim startrow As Long
Dim workrange As Range

startrow = 2
Set workrange = Sheets("Full").Range("L2: L424")
For Each myrange In workrange
    If myrange.Font.Bold Or myrange.Interior.ColorIndex = 6 Then
        Sheets("Test").Cells(startrow, 12) = myrange.Value
        startrow = startrow + 1

End If
Next

End Sub
```

Okay, thank you both. I'm almost there. My code now is:

```
Sub Button1_Click()

Dim myrange As Range
Dim startrow As Long
Dim workrange As Range

startrow = 1
Set workrange = Sheets("Full").Range("L1: L424")
For Each myrange In workrange
    If myrange.Font.Bold Or myrange.Interior.ColorIndex = 6 Then
        myrange.Resize(1, 98).Copy Sheets("Test").Cells(startrow, 12)
        startrow = startrow + 1

End If
Next

End Sub
```

But I'm missing columns A-K (1-11). My condition is based on "values" in column 12 (L), either bold font or yellow highlights, but I can only seem to post the cell values (with formatting and formulas) from rows L-CT. Any help appreciated!

Comment: You need to use `Copy` for this.

Comment: Understood - thank you! I've made some progress but am still stuck, and have edited my original question. Am very much a novice when it comes to this.

Answer (score 0):

As BigBen stated correctly you need to copy the cells to preserve all formats and formulas.

Edit: Do you really want the copied range to be pasted into column 12 of sheet Test? If so here we go...

```
Sub Button1_Click()

Dim myrange As Range
Dim startrow As Long
Dim workrange As Range
Dim wksFull As Worksheet
Dim wksTest As Worksheet

    Set wksFull = Worksheets("Full")
    Set wksTest = Worksheets("Test")
    With wksFull
        startrow = 1
        Set workrange = .Range("L1: L424")
        For Each myrange In workrange
            If myrange.Font.Bold Or myrange.Interior.ColorIndex = 6 Then
                .Range(.Cells(myrange.Row, 1), .Cells(myrange.Row, 98)).Copy _
                    wksTest.Cells(startrow, 12)
                startrow = startrow + 1
        End If
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you much! I've made some progress thanks to your edited code but am still stuck, and have edited my original question. Novice here.

Comment: No. Column 12 is where the conditions are met, but I want the pasted rows to start at ("A", 1). Changing the copy destination to: wksTest.Cells(startrow, 1) accomplishes that. Thank you SO much!